# Arcsine as a complex natural logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, logarithms

My question regards how we expess $z=sin^{-1}(w)$ as a natural logarithm in the complex plane.

What I know is that we start off with $sin(z)=w$, we know that $sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, and through this we can create the equation $ {e^{2iz}-2iwe^{iz}-1=0}$.

What I have found is that when we solve for z using the quadratic formula, we get the result $z = -i\ln(iw\pm\sqrt{1-w^2})$. However, from what I've seen on a multitude of sites, apparently $z=sin^{-1}(w)$ is solely expressed as $z = -i\ln(iw+\sqrt{1-w^2})$.

Why is the negative branch of the square root not considered? I cannot find the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Already as a function of a _real_ argument, the map $x \mapsto \sin x$ is _not_ injective, so when considering "the inverse", called arcsine, some convention has to be used when picking each inverse image. For complex numbers, it is no better. I think people try to respect the convention for real numbers (which is to pick the $y$ from $[-\pi / 2, \pi / 2]$) when they pick a convention for the complex arcus function.

Answer (score 1):

If you check for instance [Matlab's Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/asin.html?searchHighlight=asin&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#mw_7c931dd8-06af-4674-8d38-b21d51804a94)

The inverse sine is defined as:

$$
\sin^{−1}(z)=−i \log\left[i z+(1−z^2)^{1/2}\right]
$$

Also keep in mind that if this is supossed to be a function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, it can only return one complex number, so we can't consider two branches at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in $w = 0$ and you will see why. The other sign gets you a different branch of $\sin^{-1}$, but not the one you are familiar with over the reals.

Comment: Sir if we consider, $z=-i\ln(iw-\sqrt{1-w^2})$ and put $w=0$ then we get, $z=-i\ln(0-\sqrt{1}) =-i\ln(-1)$ but we know logarithmic function is not defined for negative numbers hence $z$ does not exists for $w=0$. Thus, $\sin^{-1}(0)$ does not exists! When we consider  $z=-i\ln(iw-\sqrt{1-w^2})$. Is this is the reason?